# Redirect request with JSP

Tags: java, jsp

How do I redirect a request with JSP with the path also forwarded?

Example:

```
my-domain.com/abc to www.other-domain.com/abc
```

Where 'abc' would be the request path. Also it is possible to also forward query parameters and fragment identifiers?

Comment: Maybe you do mean a **redirect**, rather than a forward?

Comment: Why need you jsp? You can use servlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't redirect fragment identifiers as they aren't passed to the server.

To do this in JSP you'll want something like the following:

```
<%
response.sendRedirect("http://www.other-domain.com" +
                       request.getContextPath() +
                       request.getServletPath() +
                       (request.getQueryString() == null ?
                           "" :
                           "?" + request.getQueryString())
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HttpServletResponse:

```
response.sendRedirect(location)
```